# Why wrap layout overflows when it shouldn't

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently trying to use a `Wrap` layout to display some icons, but the icons overflow out of the screen. As of my understanding, isn't the `Wrap` layout exactly to avoid overflows? How could I fix this instead? I tried to put it inside a `ConstrainedBox` but without success.

[image: See the "Aéroport" line, it overflows]

As you can see, it overflows on the "Aéroport" line.

**My code**:

```
new Container(
    child: new Wrap(
        spacing: 4.0,
        runSpacing: 4.0,
        children: row) //List<Widget> row = *function to generate a list of icons*
);
```

**The actual function**:

```
Widget lineIcon({String lineCode, String lineColor, double width, double height, double fontSize, int ratio}) {   
    var r = ratio == null ? 100 : ratio;
    var colorInt = int.parse('0xFF' + lineColor);
    return new Container(
        height: height == null ? 32.0*r/100 : height,
        width: width == null ? 48.0*r/100 : width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(colorInt),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(16.0, 16.0)),
          border: new Border.all(
            color: Color(colorInt),
          ),
        ),
        child: new Align(
          child: new Text(lineCode,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: fontSize == null ? 20.0*r/100 : fontSize,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ));
  }
```

**Version**: Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Mac OS X 10.13.4

Comment: We  need more code. Can you send the whole item builder ?

Comment: And also flutter version as well, I've fixed a few issues regarding wrap overflows so this might be a bug

Comment: try to create a horizontal list view then

Comment: @ShyjuM You mean putting some horizontal list views inside my wrap ? Or just replacing my wrap by it ? Wouldn’t the latter not fix the issue ?

Comment: Container[Parent of Wrap Widget] is Redundant. Try removing it.